# Условие в обновлении значений в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql

использую php и mysql. нужно составить запрос обновления значения поля по условию.  Если новое значение больше старого, то обновить.  Попытался составить такой запрос, получилось это, но оно не работает. я плохо знаю синтаксис mysql.
    "UPDATE `auctions` SET `rate` = ? WHERE `rate` > (SELECT `rate` FROM `auctions` WHERE `id` = ?) AND `id` = ?"

помогите составить рабочий запрос.

Answer (score 1):

вопрос решен. я во-первых не правильно составил условия запроса, а во вторых... ну вообщем сами посмотрите
"UPDATE `auctions` SET `rate` = ? WHERE ? > `rate` AND `id` = ?"